# CakePHP 3.8 or 4.0, based on SendGrid & Twig support?

Tags: php, cakephp, twig, sendgrid

I'm moving a non-framework PHP project into CakePHP. The question is whether to begin with CakePHP 3.8 or CakePHP 4.0. I'm looking at support for certain plugins.

We use SendGrid, but the CakePHP-integration plugin is only supported by CakePHP 3.x. We use twig, but the twig-view and legacy-twig-view plugins require CakePHP 4.x. We also need to generate PDFs and excel files, but those can be done with standalone PHP packages (via composer) so the CakePHP version does not matter.

I have experience with CakePHP 2.x/3.x, and CakePHP 4.0 is described as primarily a cleanup release. So perhaps the best solution would be to produce/contribute a CakePHP 4.x version of the SendGrid plugin.

What is my best approach for using both SendGrid and twig with a new CakePHP project, 3.x or 4.x?

Comment: https://github.com/Iandenh/cakephp-sendgrid/tree/4x/src/Mailer

Comment: @Salines - make this an answer and I'll accept it. That's what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also CakePHP 4 branch:

https://github.com/Iandenh/cakephp-sendgrid/tree/4x

You can also always build your own or clone one cakephp3 plugin and update code to work with cakephp 4.